# What bibliography style(s) (for bibtex) to use for a french computer science (engineering) thesis?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, french, engineering

I want an **author-date** style which has a **french** version possibly

for now I have

```
\bibliography{my-bib-file}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: See `biblatex`: it is `babel -aware. It defines 4 variants of the `author-year` style. If you compile the bibliography with `biber`, it understands `utf8`.

Comment: @Bernard please see my edit.
I tried **author-year** instead of **apalike** but it didn't work

Comment: Do you know there also exists a `biblatex-apa` package?

Comment: I'm not interested in apa (actually I want something to get rid of it). My topic is on computer science not psychology so I'd like to have a bibliography style that goes with it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of an author-year style french bibliography. The `autolang=other` option allows to have strings translated for the language of a  bibliographic item, if it has a `langid=` field.

```
\documentclass[12pt,german, english,french]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}% recommended in output (biblatex)
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, autolang=other]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{otherbibli.bib}
@online{msdn2,
    label = {MSDN2},
    title = {Comparatif entre C\# et Visual Basic .NET},
    author = {Microsoft},
    date = {2014-01-01},
    url = {http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308470},
    urldate = {2014-04-12}
}

@Book{Neu,
  Title = {Mathematische Grundlagen des Quantummechanick},
  Author = {John von Neumann},
  Date = {1996},
  Edition = {2},
  Publisher = {Springer},
  Langid = {german}
}

@Book{Schwartz,
  Title = {Topologie générale et Analyse fonctionnelle},
  Author = {Laurent Schwartz},
  Date = {1970},
  Publisher = {Hermann}
}

@Article{Wigner,
  Title = {On Unitary Representations of the Inhomogeneous Lorentz Group},
  Author = {Eugene P. Wigner},
  Date = {1939},
  Journaltitle = {Ann. Math.},
  Number = {1},
  Pages = {149-204},
  Series = {2},
  Volume = {40}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{otherbibli.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliographie}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I couldn't make your example work for me. I have the citations when I cite but no bibliography. I'm using _Texstudio_ if this can help.

Comment: Also the citation are not between brackets. Is this a problem ?

Comment: I don't think so, but anyway, one of thge strengths of `biblatex` is that it is comparatively easy to customise, as it uses a LaTeX-like syntax.

Comment: Your example didn't work for me (I have no bibliography). How are you compiling it ?

Comment: `pdflatex -> biber -> pdflatex -> pdflatex`.